# padding between table components not working

Tags: html, css

I have a table.

```
          <table style="margin-left: 20px" class="tg">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg- 0lax">Question 1</td>
                   
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg-0lax">Answwer 1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg- 0lax">Question 2</td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg- 0lax">Answer 2</td>
             </tr>
```

I want the margin between the question 1 and the answer 1 2px. And the margin between the answer 1 and question 2 , 10 px. I cant get i done. I did try the following things: style="margin-bottom / margin-top in the  and , al well as padding 2px. But both doesnt work

Comment: hello, can you please put your css code ?

Answer (score 0):

`<td></td>` and `<tr></tr>` cant be given a margin. Although you can give them a `padding` when you set `display: block;` Then you can go on an set things like every second one should get a bigger padding at the bottom (as you wanted it). Here is a snippet with very basic styles:

```css
tr {
  display: block;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Question 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Answer 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Question 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Answer 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set border-spacing property 2px to the table, and then skip 5 rows to get 10px something like this:

```html
    <table style="margin-left: 20px;border-spacing: 2px;" class="tg">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg- 0lax" >Question 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax">Answwer 1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg- 0lax">Question 2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tg- 0lax">Answer 2</td>
          </tr>
```